# how to update a record in a table via a sql command within an IF statement

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, sql-update

I'm trying to close out a record, where I have a True/False column inside a table.  Code below, I keep getting a compile error expected end of statement.  What am I missing?  It will only be one record that is True at any given time.

```
If Me.butCompleteFlight.Value = True Then 
    UPDATE tblFlightRecords SET strWorkingRecord = FALSE WHERE strWorkingRecord = TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't mix SQL code and VBA code like that.
You can execute the update statement with the method [`DoCmd.RunSQL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.runsql):

```
If Me.butCompleteFlight.Value = True Then 
    Dim SQL As String 
    SQL = "UPDATE tblFlightRecords SET strWorkingRecord = FALSE WHERE strWorkingRecord = TRUE"
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry I'm super new to all this and just trying to fix a process that takes someone almost 50% of their working week to a more manageable few button pushes.

Comment: @Cam if this answer solved your problem consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in no application layer language (from Java to Python to VBA) can you submit an SQL query by itself on a separate line. SQL is a special-purpose, *separate* language compared to a general-purpose language. Hence, it is not recognized in app layers.

You must invoke the SQL statement with an interface or API object. In MS Access VBA, there are many ways to run action queries, some of which support parameterization.

**DoCmd Interface**

1. [DoCmd.OpenQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.openquery) *(requires a saved query in advance)*
2. [DoCmd.RunSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.runsql) *(runs a string query)*

**DAO API**

3. [QueryDef.Execute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydef-execute-method-dao) *(requires a saved or temporary query and supports [parameterization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/parameters-collection-dao))*
4. [Database.Execute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-execute-method-dao) *(runs a string or saved query)*

**ADO API**

5. [Connection.Execute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/execute-method-ado-connection?view=sql-server-ver15) *(runs a string or stored query)*
6. [Command.Execute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/execute-method-ado-command?view=sql-server-ver15) *(runs a string or stored query, supports [parameterization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameters-collection-ado?view=sql-server-ver15))*

Do note: VBA is not the only way to connect to MS Access databases. Java, Python, C#, and still others can as well but you must adhere to the chosen SQL API, module, or library. None of which allows SQL to be run by itself on a separate line.

Comment: Thank you I will take a look into this further.  Baby steps...  sadly this is no where in my wheelhouse for my primary job.  I'm just trying to fumble thru this the best I can.