# Passing values in Database.Execute returns an error 3061

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I assigned the code below to a commandbutton.

It returns an error (3061).

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblVerlof(Aanmaakdatum, VerlofDatum, VerlofReden, Aantal, me.VerlofPoule, Notitie, Status)VALUES(now(), me.startdatum, 2, me.txturen, me.verlofpoule, me.txttitel, 2)"
```

Comment: You should include the full error message in your question. And of course look up what that error means. Seems like this is one you should be able to get on your own.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run-time error '3061'. Too few parameters. Expected 1. (Access 2007)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445062/run-time-error-3061-too-few-parameters-expected-1-access-2007)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the [multiple ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59493412/1422451) to run action queries in MS Access VBA, for `Database.Execute` you cannot pass form values directly in SQL and should avoid concatenating values from VBA into the SQL.

Instead, consider using  `DoCmd.OpenQuery` or `QueryDefs.Execute` to parameterize form controls into SQL statement:

**DoCmd.OpenQuery** approach

SQL *(save as a query object)*

```sql
INSERT INTO tblVerlof(Aanmaakdatum, VerlofDatum, VerlofReden, Aantal, 
                      VerlofPoule, Notitie, Status)
VALUES(NOW(), Forms!myform!startdatum, 2, Forms!myform!txturen, 
       Forms!myform!verlofpoule, Forms!myform!txttitel, 2)
```

VBA *(no need to close action queries)*

```vb
DoCmd.OpenQuery "mySavedQuery"
```

---

**QueryDefs.Execute** approach

SQL *(save as a query object and `PARAMETERS` clause is valid in Access SQL)*

```sql
PARAMETERS prm_startdatum Date, prm_txturen Text,
           prm_verlofpoule Text, prm_txttitel Text;
INSERT INTO tblVerlof(Aanmaakdatum, VerlofDatum, VerlofReden, Aantal, 
                      VerlofPoule, Notitie, Status)
VALUES(NOW(), prm_startdatum, 2, prm_txturen, 
       prm_verlofpoule, prm_txttitel, 2)
```

VBA

```vb
Dim qdef As QueryDef

Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")

qdef!prm_startdatum   = Me.startdatum
qdef!prm_txturen      = Me.txturen
qdef!prm_verlofpoule  = Me.verlofpoule
qdef!prm_txttitel     = Me.txttitel

qdef.Execute

Set qdef = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

In the list of columns:

```
(Aanmaakdatum, VerlofDatum, VerlofReden, Aantal, me.VerlofPoule, Notitie, Status)
```

what is `me.VerlofPoule`?
This is not a column's name, right?
Change it to the correct column name.

Answer (score 0):

I found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445062/run-time-error-3061-too-few-parameters-expected-1-access-2007) that error 3061 is ""Run-time error '3061'. Too few parameters."  According to the answer on that question, the insert column names could be wrong.

It looks like the query has a column named `me.VerlofPoule`.  That is also the value that is supposed to go into this column.  Maybe this is supposed to be the name of a different column?

Answer (score 0):

The fifth column in your `insert` statement isn't a valid field name:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblVerlof(Aanmaakdatum, VerlofDatum, VerlofReden, Aantal, me.VerlofPoule, Notitie, Status)VALUES(now(), me.startdatum, 2, me.txturen, me.verlofpoule, me.txttitel, 2)"
                                                                         This field -----^
```

If the field name is represented by the value held by the `VerlofPoule` control on your form, then you would need to concatenate the field name, as it will not be evaluated when the SQL statement is executed.

Similarly, the `Me.XXX` items in your `values` clause will also not be evaluated, instead, you should either use parameters or reference the form controls using the syntax: `Forms![YourForm]![YourControl]`